# Npgsql: Old floating point representation for timestamps not supported

Tags: c#, postgresql, floating-point, npgsql

I've written a basic script that syncs data from a PostgreSQL database to another system, which executes in my test/development environment without issue, using:

- PostgreSQL 9.4
- Npgsql dll version 3.0.3

Once we ran the script in the live production environment, we hit the following error:

> "Old floating point representation for timestamps not supported"

Researching the issue, I found this is related to a "deprecated compile-time option of PostgreSQL which switches to a floating-point representation of some date/time fields. Npgsql (currently) does not support this mode."

[Here is a link to the relevant source code](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Npgsql/3.0.0-beta0001/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Npgsql/Npgsql/TypeHandlers/DateTimeHandlers/IntervalHandler.cs?ImageName=Npgsql).

In production, the PostgreSQL server is running version 8.3, and for internal reasons, the server manager has declined to upgrade the PostgreSQL server at this time. (Current Npgsql version doesn't officially support PosgreSQL prior to version 9. doh!)

Question(s):

- Is there any way to modify the PostgreSQL 8.3 "integer_datetimes"
  configuration setting without fully reinstalling the application or
  upgrading?
- Alternately, is there any way to downgrade my Npgsql dlls to an older version where this configuration setting was supported?
- Any recommendations for an alternative to Npgsql if necessary? I was thinking about refactoring the code to use ADO.NET (but I'm not sure if that would be recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not one hundred percent sure about this, but Npgsql 2.2.7 should be able to work properly with the PostgreSQL legacy floating point format since it uses text transfer to read and write values not binary. This should allow you to interact with the old database.

However, it's severely discouraged to continue using PostgreSQL 8.3 in any way - 8.3 reached its end-of-life on February 2013... You should definitely experiment with migrating to 9.4 simply by dumping the data and restoring it into the new environment, it may work well.

Also note that while new versions, like 3.0.4, in general do work on pre-9.0 PostgreSQL - it's just that they're not tested in any way and we probably won't fix any non-trivial bugs you may run across.

Comment: Downgrading to Npgsql 2.2.7 resolved the "Old floating point representation for timestamps not supported" error I was encountering. Thank you for the assistance! I fully agree that using PosgreSQL 8.3 is not ideal, but in this instance I unfortunately don't have any control over the decision to upgrade or not, and had to find a working solution for the PostgreSQL 8.3 database in place. On the bright side, I already have a copy of my project that is using the latest Npgsql version for when the database upgrade can occur. Thank you again!

Comment: I have a PostgreSQL 9.3 instance I don't control with `integer_datetimes` disabled. Npgsql 2.2.7 works for timestamps, but some arrays throw I presume something to do with nulls in value type arrays. Upgrading to 3.2.5 fixed the arrays but now timestamps throw. Why was the timestamp support removed (looks like maybe commit `1f140e5`)?

Comment: timestamp support wasn't removed - Npgsql 3.0 switched from reading/writing text representation of values to binary, i.e. instead of parsing human-readable representations of timestamps, a simple binary value is read instead (much more efficient, easier to maintain etc.). Unfortunately in *very* old versions of PostgreSQL the default binary representation is unsupported by Npgsql, although you can still recompile as explained above for the new representation.

Comment: By the way, unless I'm mistaken the new timestamp binary format ("64-bit integer datetime") has been the default for a long time, long before 9.3. So someone specifically compiled your PostgreSQL 9.3 to use an ancient, obsolete timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

According to a thread here:

http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/103f2g9gsr/integer-datetime-8-2-8-4-differences

I noted this that may be helpful to you:

> The first item listed under "Observe the following incompatibilities"
>   in the 8.4 release notes is
>
> Use 64-bit integer datetimes by default (Neil Conway)
>
> Previously this was selected by configure's
>   --enable-integer-datetimes option. To retain the old behavior, build with --disable-integer-datetimes.

Maybe that is helpful in figuring out how to disable/enable integer-datetime.
What version of Postgre-SQL are you on?

Comment: Hi Vinny, Thanks for taking the time to investigate and help me troubleshoot this issue. The live server running the task is using PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3. In my development environment I'm using 9.4. Unfortunately I don't think there is any way for me to change the datime integer setting on the PostgreSQL 8.3 instance without upgrading, and currently the server admin has said that isn't an option. So I think I need to use a different method than Npgsql (or older Npgsql dlls) for pulling my dataset from the DB.

Comment: Could you set the legacy flag in the 9.4 environment via the code in the link I provided:
`build with --disable-integer-datetimes`

This is a hack but what about casting the dates as strings before you insert them into the target DB and then recasting those strings back to whatever format they should be in.

ADO.Net seems like it will handle this for you nicely in place of Npgsql without casting anything but it was just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

> Npgsql, ASP.NET Core 2.2:System.NotSupportedException: The deprecated
>   floating-point date/time format is not supported by Npgsql.

Hi guys! I faced this problem using asp.net core 2.2. In my case I downgraded to Npgsql version 4.0.7 and this resolved my problem.