# Teiid: deprecated floating-point date/time format is not supported by Npgsql

Tags: npgsql, teiid

I've written a C# netcoreapp 3.1 webapi app that tries to read a Teiid VDB table via Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.0.

Whenever my app reads any data like this:

```
_context.Campaigns.ToList();
```

the following error occurs:

```
NotSupportedException: The deprecated floating-point date/time format is not supported by Npgsql.
```

Googling it I've found this: [Npgsql: Old floating point representation for timestamps not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274236/npgsql-old-floating-point-representation-for-timestamps-not-supported) . Unfortunately, the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL project [stopped supporting](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/pull/2354/files) the deprecated floating-point date/time format of PostgreSQL but Teiid seems to be still using it.

I've also tried the old version 2.2.4 of Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL with a .net Core 2 app that didn't have this problem but failed to read and write double values from/to Teiid.

AFAIK, the only working way to access Teiid data from .net Core apps is via System.Data.ODBC.

Is there any configuration or tweak on Teiid to make its PostgreSQL emulation using the new integer date/time format?

Or if not, is there any plan to update the Teiid PostgreSQL emulation?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Support for this version of postgresql seems to be dropped in version 4.1 of the Npgsql driver which is used for alle 3.1+ versions of Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.

Comment: According to [TEIID-5921](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIID-5921?jql=project%20%3D%20TEIID%20AND%20component%20%3D%20ODBC), support was added for this in Teiid 14.0.0. It seems like this whas not mentioned in the Release Notes.

Answer (score 0):

> Or if not, is there any plan to update the Teiid PostgreSQL emulation?

I don't think the full context is quite captured here.  The current state of the pg emulation is that it supports the binary format only for bytea, integral, float, double, and date types.  The driver should be sending time/timestamp in text format.

If additional binary format type support is needed, that would require an enhancement.

As for what binary format to support, we need to match the expectation for the pg version that we are emulating, which is currently 8.2.  If there is a connection / session variable to control the expected format we could look to support that.

The last efforts to support npgsql were two years ago, so it's likely that their driver is now doing things that we didn't expect.  So you should log an enhancement about supporting the latest and greatest version, which could coordinate any of the subtasks.